# Почему бот ТГ не видит текстовое сообщение

Tags: python, aiogram

Бот рассылка не видит текстовую команду, не знаю почему. Вроде всё сделал без ошибок.

Вот код, на всякий перешлю полностью

```
class bot_mailing(StatesGroup):
    text = State()
    photo = State()
    state = State()

@dp.message_handler(chat_type=types.ChatType.PRIVATE, text='/mailing', chat_id=ADMIN)
async def start_mailing(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer(f'Введите текст рассылки:')
    await bot_mailing.text.set()


@dp.message_handler(chat_type=types.ChatType.PRIVATE, state=bot_mailing.text, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def mailing_text(message: types.Message, State: FSMContext):
    answer = message.text
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,
                                  inline_keyboard=[
                                      [
                                          InlineKeyboardButton(text='Добавить фотографию', callback_data='add_photo'),
                                          InlineKeyboardButton(text='Далее', callback_data='next'),
                                          InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отменить', callback_data='quit')
                                      ]
                                  ])
    await state.update_data(text = answer)
    await message.answer(text=answer, reply_markup=markup)
    await bot_mailing_text.state.set()

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='next', state=bot_mailing.text.state, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def start(call: types.CallbackQuery, state= FSMContext):
    users = await commands.select_all_users
    data = await state.get_data()
    text = data.get('text')
    await state.finish()
    for user in users:
        try:
            await dp.bot.send_message(chat_id=user.user_id, text=text)
        except Exception:
            pass
    await call.message.answer('Рассылка выполнена')


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='add_photo',state=bot_mailing.state, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def add_photo(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer('Пришлите фото')
    await bot_mailing.photo.set()

@dp.message_handler(chat_type=types.ChatType.PRIVATE, state=bot_mailing.photo, content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def mailing_text(message: types.Message, State: FSMContext):
    photo_file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
    await state.update_data(photo=photo_file_id)
    data = await state.get.data()
    text = data.get('text')
    photo = data.get('photo')

    markup= InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,
                                 inline_keyboard=[
                                     [
                                         InlineKeyboardButton(text='Далее', callback_data='next'),
                                         InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отменить', callback_data='quit')
                                     ]
                                 ])
    await message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption=text, reply_markup=markup)

@dp.callback_query_handler(text='next', state=bot_mailing.photo, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def start(call: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    users = await commands.select_all_users
    data = await state.get_data()
    text = data.get('text')
    photo = data.get('photo')
    await state.finish()
    for user in users:
        try:
            await dp.bot.send_photo(chat_id=user.user_id, photo=photo, caption=text)
        except Exception:
            pass
    await call.message.answer('Рассылка выполнена')



@dp.message_handler(chat_type=types.ChatType.PRIVATE, state=bot_mailing.photo, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def no_photo(message: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2,
                                  inline_keyboard=[
                                      [
                                          InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отменить', callback_data='quit')
                                      ]
                                  ])
    await message.answer('Пришли мне фотографию', reply_markup=markup)

@dp.message_handler(state=bot_mailing.text, chat_id=ADMIN)
async def quit(message: types.Message, state:FSMContext, text = 'quit'):
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Отмена рассылки')
```

Comment: Какой конкретно хендлер не работает

Comment: /Mailing конкрентно

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить

```
text='/mailing
```

на

```
commands=["mailing"]
```